How to extend sqs queue default policy
I have sqs queue, which has no policy defined. Queue is not owned by me, I have no idea how it is used, and I do not want to break it. I need to add permission for sending messages from different account, i.e.:
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Queue1_Policy_UUID",
   "Statement": [{
      "Sid":"Queue1_Send_Receive",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": { "AWS": [ "111122223333" ] },
      "Action": [ "sqs:SendMessage" ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:my-queue"
   }]
}

Adding such policy to queue will override default policy which grants full access to account which created the queue. I cannot find definition/equivalent of this default policy.
How can I add my statement to the queue's resource policy without breaking access in the account owning the queue?

To obtain a 'default' policy, simply create a new SQS Queue. It will display a policy like this:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__owner_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "111111111111"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SQS:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:queue-name"
    }
  ]
}


Thank you very much! I don't see it anywhere in my console, but looks very good :)

The policy you have shown will grant permission to send a message to the queue.
The safest option is to specifically add the ARN of the resource that wants to send messages to the queue. For example, if some code is using an IAM Role, you could add the permission like this:
  "Principal": { 
    "AWS": [
      "111122223333",
      "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/role-from-other-account"
    ]
  },

Or, if you wish to trust an entire AWS Account, just add that account number:
  "Principal": { 
    "AWS": [
      "111122223333",
      "123456789012"
    ]
  },

For this to work, there must also be a policy in the other account that grants the resource permission to use the SQS queue. For example, if an IAM Role in the 'other' account (Other-Role) wants to the SQS role in 'this' account (This-Account), then it would need permissions such as:
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
     {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:111122223333:queue1"
     }
   ]
}

This is because cross-account permissions must be aded to the IAM entity in the sending account and the receiving resource. This stops other people being able to access your resources unless you specifically grant permission.

What else other than principal is part of default policy? My problem is that I don't know how does default policy look like, so I do not know how to extend it with my role in principal.

If you have sufficient permissions to modify the policy, then you would have sufficient permissions to view the policy. Start by looking at the SQS queue in the management console.

When I view the policy, it's empty. No document at all.
Documentation states that The default policy allows only the queue owner to send and receive messages., however, it also lets queue owner to list queue attributes and possibly other items - I need to know what is this default policy, so I can upgrade it.
